# How to fix the loading doesn't display in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to fix the issue where the loading.. doesn't display.

here's the code:
***HTML***

```
     <div *ngIf="tempThermometer | async as temp; else loading">
        <ng-container *ngIf="temp.length !== 0; else noItems">
          <div *ngFor="let item of temp">
            {{temp.sensor}}</div>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #noItems>No Items!</ng-template>
      </div>
      <ng-template #loading>loading animation...</ng-template>
```

***TYPESCRIPT***

```
 tempThermometer = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
async getRoomList() {
    this.subscription = await this.global
      .getData(`/conditions/latest`)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.tempThermometer.next(Object.values(res['data'].map((obj: any) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            spinning: true
          };
        })));

        console.log(this.tempThermometer.value);
  });
```

}

what I want to do is to display the loading while fetching the data.

the issue here is the loading... doesn't display it automatically display the No Data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with `[]` and therefore `*ngIf="tempThermometer | async` will always be true. You have to check for its length being 0 but I see you do a check for its length being 0 and display `No Items!`

Try:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!tempLoading">
 <div *ngIf="tempThermometer | async as temp">
    <ng-container *ngIf="temp.length !== 0; else noItems">
       <div *ngFor="let item of temp">
         {{temp.sensor}}
       </div>
     </ng-container>
     <ng-template #noItems>No Items!</ng-template>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<div *ngIf="tempLoading">loading animation...</div>
```

```
tempLoading = false; // new variable to show loading or not, can initialize it to true depending on your use case
tempThermometer = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
getRoomList() { // remove async, nothing async about this function
    this.tempLoading = true;
    this.subscription = this.global
      .getData(`/conditions/latest`)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.tempThermometer.next(Object.values(res['data'].map((obj: any) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            spinning: true
          };
        })));
        this.tempLoading = false; // set the loading to false
        console.log(this.tempThermometer.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay, I made an edit to the `*ngIf` on the first div, see if it works. I am thinking the `as temp` might not work.   I made even more edits, see if they work. It is for you to play around and come with a solution. I would look into learning and using `Ngrx`/Redux whenever you get a chance.

Comment: after loading it doesn't display the no item.

Comment: I made more changes, it should now.

Comment: if it remove the async it there's an error the 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function

Comment: the loading animation... is working but after that it will not display the no items, because my data is empty.

Comment: I removed the await, I didn't see it. You don't need it, it does nothing. It should work, anyways, it is for you to get an idea and play around to get what you want.